# Can't login to Root User

Tags: ubuntu, root

I just installed Ubuntu 13.10 on VMware. I am trying to login to root from my user account using **su** command but unable to login as Terminal is saying the following :

```
su: Authentication Failed
```

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Enabling_the_root_account

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default, the Root account password is locked in Ubuntu. This means that you cannot login as Root directly or use the su command to become the Root user. However, since the Root account physically exists it is still possible to run programs with root-level privileges. This is where sudo comes in - it allows authorized users (normally "Administrative" users; for further information please refer to AddUsersHowto) to run certain programs as Root without having to know the root password.

So if you want root access then you can use `sudo` with user, which you have specified during installation. you can run root command like `sudo command` then it will ask for password.

**Update :: To unlock root account**

As @JosephR. suggested in comment, we can still become root or set root password using

```
sudo su
```

then we can run `passwd` command to set password.

[Referent Link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo)

Comment: You can still become root with `sudo su` and then set a password for root with `passwd`.

Comment: I know that you know of course. I meant this as a useful addition to your answer in case the OP really needs to become root.

Comment: @JosephR. sorry.. for my misunderstanding.. and thanks.. I'm just adding that content.

Comment: If you don't want to mix `sudo` and `su`, you can also use `sudo -Hi`

Answer (score -1):

1. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>mode</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>

   Check if login as root is ok. If not do continue...
2. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>mode</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>

   then go to path `/usr/bin`
3. `cd /usr/bin`
   then do is

   ```
   chmod u+s sudo su mount umount sg pkexec ping passwd newuidmap newgrp newgidmap ksu gpasswd fusermount expiry chsh chfn chage unix_chkpwd
   ```

   then do is

   ```
   chmod g+s wall write locate unix_chkpwd
   ```

   then change passwd root

   ```
   passwd
   ```
4. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>mode</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>

Or

5. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>mode</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>

   Then try `su` to login root

   ```
   su
   ```

   if not work do it again and change passwd user and root example my user is mizel
6. `su - mizel`

   root only
7. `su`

If not working command me :)